# Looking for three-place predicates to study anaphora

Tags: verbs, pronouns

I'm trying to check whether an anaphor is *obviative* (in [Kiparsky's (2002)](http://www.stanford.edu/~kiparsky/Papers/anaph.hierarchies-t.pdf) sense). Since my pronoun seems *subject free*, I need predicates with higher arity (ternary or four-place). An additional problem is that my language uses lexical causatives a lot, so for instance 'show' will be 'let-see' literally. And I want to have at least some predicate that is simplex in this respect.

Is there any kind of list that contains meanings that are typically represented by three-/four-place predicates in the languages of the world?

Comment: [This paper](http://www.stanford.edu/~bclevin/mrhbl08dat.pdf) would be a good online place to start. It's by the same Levin as the book you should get: _English Verb Classes and Alternations_. Look for "02.1 Dative Alternation"; there's a full characterization of the subclasses, with lists. But it's not available online. Oh, and there aren't any 4-place predicates; 3 dimensions is all we can handle, linguistically at the same time. See the [Logic Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: @jlawler Thanks for the references! Well, as for 4-place, there's _bet_ (who, whom, what, and what for). Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: And there's _buy, sell,_ and _pay,_ also from the [Commercial Transaction Frame](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf). But those are special cases evoking a complex context and syntax, like the zero-place ompersonal predicate `RAIN()`. Normally 3-place predicates are as far as it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after looking at the references jlawler suggested and just browsing around I realised that there are so many three-place predicates that I probably wouldn't want to have a full list. I'm editing the question slightly to reflect that.

However, the important thing is that very few ones suit my anaphora needs. The restriction is that (the) two objects are semantic coarguments and could be animate and allow reasonable identity.

The examples are: *show x x (in the mirror)*, *recommend x x*, *tell x about x*, and, probably, *praise/criticise* (if the language allows the goal argument).